# Dealing with two oneToOne fields on Doctrine entity pointing on the same related entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with Symfony2 (2.4-dev) and Doctrine2,

I've got an Entity defined in MyObject.orm.yml as:

```
NS\ApiBundle\Entity\MyObject:
    type: entity
    table: my_objects
    indexes:
        moderator_id:
            columns:
                - moderator_id
        author_id:
            columns:
                - author_id
    id:
        id:
            id: true
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    oneToOne:
        author:
            targetEntity: User
            joinColumn:
                name: author_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    oneToOne:
        moderator:
            targetEntity: User
            joinColumn:
                name: moderator_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    fields:
        created:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
        updated:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
        published:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
        title:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

As you can see there is two oneToOne fields pointing on an User entity
The problem is, if I ask Doctrine to give me theses oneToOne it won't work for both.

In the MyObject class

```
$this->getAuthor()->getFullname(); // this work
$this->getModerator()->getFullname(); // this doesn't
```

Error is: *Error: Call to a member function getFullname() on a non-object (...)*

If I remove the author oneToOne the getModerator() will work, and vice-versa.
Note: the user id pointed could be sometime the same for author and moderator (is it a problem)

Am I doing something wrong here? Is that a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
oneToOne:
    author:
        targetEntity: User
        joinColumn:
            name: author_id
            referencedColumnName: id
oneToOne:
    moderator:
        targetEntity: User
        joinColumn:
            name: moderator_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

to

```
oneToOne:
    author:
        targetEntity: User
        joinColumn:
            name: author_id
            referencedColumnName: id
    moderator:
        targetEntity: User
        joinColumn:
            name: moderator_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

You only need 1 `oneToOne` section

Its absolutely fine to define an entity in multiple relationships

Comment: I can't test right now, but I'm pretty sure you get my error :)